# SlowBuffer Messages if using console.log in zmq on('data'...)

Tags: node.js, zeromq

I am trying to understand why I get these warnings/infos in the terminal once I am using console.log in the on('data') method of a zmq subscriber:

```
<SlowBuffer 7b 22 74 79 70 65 22 3a 22 75 70 64 61 74 65 4c 69 67 68 74 73 22 2c 22 63 6f 6e 66 69 67 22 3a 22 31 31 31 30 31 31 30 30 31 31 30 30 31 31 31 30 22 7d ...>
```

The code is this:

```
subscriber.on("message", function(data){
    //if (debug)
    //  console.log(data);

    let msg = JSON.parse(data);

    if (ready)
    {
        sendString(msg.config); //config is a string, not an array!
    }

});
```

If the console statement above is not commented out, I get the SlowBuffer messages. What is worse, it seems the connection somehow stalls sometimes, too. I thought that is one of the core advantages of zmq - e.g. in case the connection drops or becomes unrsponsive, it is trying to reconnect.

Any tips or issues you see in above code? And again, what is the SlowBuffer - and why does it occur when console.log is used?

Answer (score 0):

you are not using buffer methods correctly i don't believe it's an error of zeroMQ module..

[About Slow Buffer Class](http://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_slowbuffer)

what you should try in your code is

```
if (debug){
 console.log(data.toString('hex'));
}
```

also you cannot raw parse the data if its a buffer

use `.toJSON()` method or make it a string with `.toString('utf8')` before using `JSON.parse`